# Relation of VIN of a car with emission norms of a country it is sold

Tags: obd-ii, electronic-control-module, emissions, obd, vin

A VIN of a car determines the country of manufacture. So if a car has a VIN of Canada (CARB emission standard) and is sold in India (BS-IV emission standard), will the car comply with BS-IV standards?
Since the VIN is of Canada, don't that mean the ECU has been coded according to CARB rules? Or do the ECU coding of the emission limits happen according to the country the car is sold?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the country of manufacture has a lot less to do with emissions than the destination country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cars are manufactured to meet the emission standards of the country it is intended to be sold in. If the car was manufactured in Canada with the intent to be sold in India, it will be designed to meet the emission standards of India.

However, if you buy a car in North America and ship it to India, that's a whole other story. Some countries only test the emissions from the vehicle, some countries conduct a visual mechanical inspection as well. If the car was not manufactured for the country it is being inspected for, it would likely fail a mechanical inspection as each country has it's own little quirks about emission equipment (such as catalytic converters and EGR systems), and some even restrict which engine you can have to those that had been previously certified for that country.

Comment: @tlhlngan 'each country has it's own little quirks about emission equipment (such as catalytic converters and EGR systems)' - Can you please elaborate this statement, I didn't quite get that

Comment: As stated here --> https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-countries-in-which-new-cars-are-not-required-to-have-catalytic-converters-and-so-most-are-still-sold-without-them South Africa does not require catalytic converters, whereas North America, Europe and Japan do.

Comment: So extending the discussion to Mode 01 PID 01 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_1_PID_01) of OBD-II, if the car is manufactured to be sold in India, and India doesn't have OBD-II emission test (Tail pipe inspection is used in India), does the Pass, Fail, Vehicle not ready make sense?